# Powers of AM-GM-HM triples

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, riemannian-geometry, means

Let AM, GM, HM respectively denote the arithmetic, geometric and harmonic mean. An elementary consequence of [Maclaurin's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality) shows that $$\text{AM}^{n-1} \text{HM} \geq \text{GM}^n.$$

Relating to the following problem I raised on MO, concerning an [alternative to a well-known trace estimate in Riemannian Geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397787/alternative-to-well-known-trace-estimate-in-riemannian-geometry), I'm an interested in whether an inequality of the form $$\text{AM}^a \text{HM}^b \geq \lambda \text{GM}^c,$$ for $a,b,c, \lambda >0$ forces $a = n-1, b = 1$ and $c=n$? Here, $\lambda$ is a negligible numerical constant.

Of course, the means all scale homogeneously of degree $1$, and therefore, an elementary scaling argument forces $a+b = c$. Moreover, taking various powers of the original inequality should be deemed equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some thoughts**

*Fact 1*:  Let $n \ge 2$ be a positive integer. There exist positive real constants $a, b, \lambda$ such that
$\mathrm{AM}^a \mathrm{HM}^b \ge \lambda \mathrm{GM}^{a + b}$ holds for all positive reals $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ if and only if $a/b \ge n - 1$.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

“if” part: The inequality is written as
$\left(\frac{\mathrm{AM}}{\mathrm{GM}}\right)^{a/b} \ge \lambda^{1/b}\frac{\mathrm{GM}}{\mathrm{HM}}$.
Since $\mathrm{AM}^{n - 1} \mathrm{HM} \ge \mathrm{GM}^n$
which is written as $(\frac{\mathrm{AM}}{\mathrm{GM}})^{n - 1} \ge \frac{\mathrm{GM}}{\mathrm{HM}}$, noting that $\frac{\mathrm{AM}}{\mathrm{GM}} \ge 1$, we have $\left(\frac{\mathrm{AM}}{\mathrm{GM}}\right)^{a/b} \ge (\frac{\mathrm{AM}}{\mathrm{GM}})^{n - 1}\ge \frac{\mathrm{GM}}{\mathrm{HM}}$, and the desired result follows.

“only if” part: Let $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_{n - 1} = x$ and $x_n = 1$.
From $\frac{\mathrm{AM}^a \mathrm{HM}^b}{\mathrm{GM}^{a + b}} \ge \lambda$,
we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\mathrm{AM}^a \mathrm{HM}^b}{\mathrm{GM}^{a + b}} \ge \lambda$
which results in $a/b \ge n - 1$ (easy).

We are done.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! In particular, this gives a uniqueness relation on the power means, which is interesting/disappointing, especially in light of the application.

Comment: @ABBC You are welcome.